# Read binary file: Matlab differs from R and python

Tags: python, r, matlab

I am trying to recreate a Matlab script that reads a binary file in either R or python. Here is a link to a the test.bin data: https://github.com/AndrewHFarkas/BinaryReadTest

Matlab

```
FilePath = 'test.bin'
fid=fopen(FilePath,'r','b');
VersionStr=fread(fid,7,'char')
Version=fread(fid,1,'int16')
SizeFormat='float32'
DataFormat='float32'
EegMegStatus=fread(fid,1,SizeFormat)
NChanExtra=fread(fid,1,SizeFormat)
TrigPoint=fread(fid,1,'float32')
DataTypeVal=fread(fid,1,'float32')
TmpSize=fread(fid,2,SizeFormat)
AvgMat=fread(fid,1,DataFormat)
```

Matlab output:

```
VersionStr =
86
101
114
115
105
111
110
Version =
8
SizeFormat =
'float32'
DataFormat =
'float32'
EegMegStatus =
1
NChanExtra =
0
TrigPoint =
1
DataTypeVal =
0
TmpSize =      
65
1076
AvgMat =
-12.9650
```

This is my closest attempt with python (I found some of this code from a different stackoverflow answer:

```
import numpy as np
import array

def fread(fid, nelements, dtype):
     if dtype is np.str:
         dt = np.uint8  # WARNING: assuming 8-bit ASCII for np.str!
     else:
         dt = dtype

     data_array = np.fromfile(fid, dt, nelements)
     data_array.shape = (nelements, 1)

     return data_array

fid = open('test.bin', 'rb');
print(fread(fid, 7, np.str)) # so far so good!
[[ 86]
 [101]
 [114]
 [115]
 [105]
 [111]
 [110]]

#both of these options return 2048
print(fread(fid, 1, np.int16))
np.fromfile(fid, np.int16, 1)
```

And no matter what else I've tried I can't get any of the same numbers past that point. I have tried using little and big endian settings, but maybe not correctly.

If it helps, here is my closest attempt in R:

```
newdata = file("test.bin", "rb")
version_char = readBin(newdata, "character", n=1)
version_char
[1] "Version" # this makes sense because the first 7 bytes to spell Version

version_num = readBin(newdata, "int", size = 1 , n = 1, endian = "little")
version_num
[1] 8 #correct number
```

And nothing after that matches. This is were I get really confused because I was only able to get 8 with a (byte) size = 1 for the version_num, but an int16 should be two bytes as far as I understand. I have tried this code below to read in a float as suggested in another post:

```
readBin(newdata, "double", size = 4 , n = 1, endian = "little")
```

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

struct is in general what you would use to unpack binary data

```
>>> keys = "VStr vNum EegMeg nChan trigPoint dType tmpSize[0] tmpSize[1] avgMat".split()
>>> dict(zip(keys,struct.unpack_from(">7sh7f",open("test.bin","rb").read())))
{'nChan': 0.0, 'EegMeg': 1.0, 'dType': 0.0, 'trigPoint': 1.0, 'VStr': 'Version', 'avgMat': -12.964995384216309, 'vNum': 8, 'tmpSize[0]': 65.0, 'tmpSize[1]': 1076.0}
```

the unpack string says unpack a string of 7 characters, followed by a short int followed by 7 float32